# BlazeDS + Flash Builder: on setting web-application parameters

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, blazeds

I have a working Flex/BlazeDS application (for simple AMF remoting) with the following settings:

server-config.xml:

```
<channel-definition id="my-secure-amf" class="mx.messaging.channels.SecureAMFChannel">
    <endpoint url="https://www.mydomain.com:443/myapp/messagebroker/amfsecure.amf" 
          class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint"/>
    <properties>
        <add-no-cache-headers>false</add-no-cache-headers>
        <polling-enabled>false</polling-enabled>
    </properties>
</channel-definition>
```

and in Flash Builder 4.6 > Properties > Flex Server:

```
Root URL: http://www.mydomain.com/myapp
Context Root: /myapp/
```

The problem was I had all of my java files sitting in ONE directory at:

```
WEB-INF/classes/
```

and simply used the system default package (e.g. no package specified in the java files). Eventually, the sheer number of files became overwhelming. To improve my organization, I started using packages and in the process I created the following directories:

```
WEB-INF/classes/com/mydomain/
WEB-INF/classes/com/mydomain/mytools/
WEB-INF/classes/com/mydomain/hr/
WEB-INF/classes/com/mydomain/utilities/
etc...
```

Now there's no java files sitting in the `WEB-INF/classes/` directory (they've been moved to it's various subdirectories).

My question is how to modify the `services-config.xml` file and/or Flash Builder > Properties > Flex Server settings? I've tried many different settings and I'm always getting the following error:

```
Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Status 404: url:...
```

My thinking is that most people organize their projects using a `WEB-INF/classes/com/mydomain/` architecture, so I'm hoping someone can share with me what their settings look like.

Adobe's website gives the following information but I don't see what I'm doing wrong: `The root folder specifies the top-level directory of the web application (the directory that contains the WEB-INF directory). The root URL specifies the URL of the web application, and the context root specifies the root of the web application.`

Thanks in advance for any comments/hints what to try.

UPDATE1:

Here's my destination (from remoting-config.xml):

```
<destination id="mySecureDestination">
    <channels>
        <channel ref="my-secure-amf"/>
    </channels>
        <properties>
            <source>myApplicationClass</source> 
            <scope>application</scope>
        </properties>
</destination>
```

Comment: Could you show us the definition of your destination(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source tag of your `destination` definition, you must write the full classpath of the class you are targetting. So assuming that you moved `myApplicationClass` to `WEB-INF/classes/com/mydomain/`, this should read:

```
<destination id="mySecureDestination">
    <channels>
        <channel ref="my-secure-amf"/>
    </channels>
        <properties>
            <source>com.mydomain.myApplicationClass</source> 
            <scope>application</scope>
        </properties>
</destination>
```

Comment: Thanks RIAstar, I'll give it a try. Could you confirm that I don't need to change `services-config.xml` nor any of the Flash Builder settings for the server as shown above?

Comment: @ggkmath Not from what I can see and if everything worked before you moved the classes. (I'm assuming you use the destination name in your service configuration on the client side)